# Find Representative Matrix of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given $L:R^{3}\to R^{3}$ for which  $L(\begin{bmatrix}x ,y ,z\end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}2x+y+3z\\x+2y+z\\x-y+2z
\end{bmatrix}$ and the basis $U={[2,0,1],[1,1,0],[0,-1,1]}$ I have to find the representative matrix $A_{L,U}$ of $L$ in the basis $U$. I don't know how to solve it. I would write the matrix as $\begin{bmatrix}2&+1&+3\\1&+2&+1\\1&-1&+2
\end{bmatrix}$ but obviously it is a matrix of the canonical basis of $R^3$. So how can I solve it? What is the method? Please give clear answer. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You have to find the matrix $T$ that transform the canonical basis in the new basis, and multply $LT$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P$ is the change of basis matrix from the canonical basis to the basis $U$, and $A$ the matrix  of $L$ in the canonical basis, the matrix of $B$ of $L$ in the basis $U$ is given by:
$$ B=P{-1}AP$$
So you have to compute the inverse of $P$ first.

$P$ is the matrix with the coordinates of the vectors in $U$ as column vectors:
$$P=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1  & 0\\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 &0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
To obtain the inverse of $P$, use Gauß's pivot method, with elementary operations on rows until you've transformed it into the unit matrix $I$, and perform the same transformations on $I$. The final transform of $I$ is $P^{-1}$.

You may as well use elementary operations on columns, but *not*  on both rows and columns.

Comment: Yes I know it as a definition but practically how can I find the matrix $P$ ?

Comment: @Dipok:  See my updated answer.